# ReportViewer error - The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, reportviewer, report-viewer2010

I am using Visual Studio 2010 SP1, .Net 4.0, SSRS 2008 R2, Windows XP Professional

The following is the error I am getting, when I am trying to run reports using Visual Studio 2010 (debug mode) on my development machine.

> The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized.

The web.config has settings:

```xml
<authentication mode="Windows" />
<identity impersonate="true" />
```

I have:

- set up a class for `WindowsImpersonationCredentials : IReportServerCredentials`.
- checked the ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials before running the report and it has the user ID who is logged into the machine, but ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials. ImpersonateUser is null just before running the report.
- The web application and the SSRS are on the same development machine.
- Changed the DisableloopCheck to 1 in the registry - didn't make any difference.

The report works fine when I run it directly from the report manager. The same code works fine on the server suprsingly but not my local machine (debug mode).

Couldn't figure out what on earth is going on behind the scenes. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Any suggestions please..